# Sort a Dictionary<Point, int> based on its key

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<Point, int> MyDic`, the `Point` class is defined as below:

```
public class Point
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

How can I sort the `MyDic` based on its `Key` using `LINQ`? I want to order by `X` then by `Y`.

For example if my dictionary is like below:

```
Key (Point (X,Y))          Value (int)
--------------------------------------
(8,9)                      6
(5,4)                      3
(1,4)                      2
(11,14)                    1
```

it will be like this after sorting:

```
Key (Point (X,Y))          Value (int)
--------------------------------------
(1,4)                      2
(5,4)                      3
(8,9)                      6
(11,14)                    1
```

Comment: If you are going to be storing your custom class in a dictionary you really should be overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This applies to all the custom classes that I'm using in a dictionary or only the dictionaries I'm going to sort?

Comment: If you created a dictionary without a custom comparer it will use `Comparer<T>.Default` which in turn uses `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)` on the class. So for every dictionary you use your choices are to either have a class that implements `Equals(` and `GetHashCode()` or use a dictionary that uses a custom comparer that does not rely on `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` built in to the type (because it provides it's own implementation of those two).

Comment: So as far as I'm not sorting the dictionary I'm fine with using custom classes in a dictionary right?

Comment: As long as you are creating the dictionary passing in a `IComparer<TKey>` to the constructor or the custom class overrides `GetHashCode()` and `Equals(object)`, yes. But there are other gotchas, like the key [must be immutable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx) while it is being used as the key for a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks Scott, now I get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OrderBy` and `ThenBy` should do the trick for you:

```
MyDic.OrderBy(x => x.Key.X)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Key.Y)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value)
```

Comment: Ummm, Why the .`ToDictonary` at the end? Dictionaries will not preserve any kind of ordering, the best you could do is a `SortedList<Point,int>` or similar.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes but that doesn't mean you can't sort a dictionary. https://dotnetfiddle.net/QajyMh

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Selman answered based on my question which I have used the Dictionary, Sortedlist seems a good idea I'll try that. Thanks. The dictionary is working though.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain By the way, how can we use SortedList since there is nothing as ToSortedList(), you mean my original collection should be a SortedList?

Comment: @Vahid just make the original collection a SortedList (or SortedDictionary). As to the .NET fiddle example, that is just getting lucky, the enumeration order of a Dictionary is "Undefined" so while using the current version of the .NET CLR with your input set may have worked it is not guaranteed that other versions of the .NET CLR will have the same behavior nor will other input sets.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Unfortunately my original collection is itself the result of another `LINQ` expression. I don't know how to create it as SortedList since LINQ doesn't have ToSordtedList()? :s

Comment: @Vahid You can make a `ToSortedList()` extension method your self trivially. If you get stuck ask a new question on it.

Comment: @Vahid sortedlist has a constructor that takes an IDictionary<T, V> so you can just pass your dictionary.

Comment: @Selman22 Thanks, So I'll convert my original dictionary to a sortedlist then in your solution I'll replace ToDictionary with ...?

Comment: @Vahid create a "extension method" that basicly will be `public static SortedList<T,V> ToSortedList(this IDictionary<T,V> dict) { return new SortedList<T,V>(dict); }` you can can just change the above code to `MyDict.ToSortedList()`;

Comment: I'll try this, if I can't get it right I'll post it as a new question. I really appreciate your help Scott.